# "git clean -f" doesn't leave an empty directory

Tags: git

If I have a directory *app* in my repository with a single, untracked file in it and I execute `git clean -f`, I get the message: *Not removing app/*  and the untracked file is still there.

But if I have an additional, tracked file within the same directory and I execute the exact same command then the untracked file is removed successfully.

So my question is: Why is Git trying to delete the directory if it would be empty after cleaning it from untracked files?

Below is a script which reproduces the behavior. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create new empty repo
mkdir myrepo && cd myrepo
git init

# Create app directory with main.c
mkdir app
touch app/main.c

# Try to delete main.c with git clean -> Not working
git clean -f

# Add helper.c to app directory and add to index
touch app/helper.c
git add app/helper.c

# Try to delete main.c with git clean -> Now it's working
git clean -f
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the `-d` option for `git clean` to remove untracked directories.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it is not clear to me why Git wants to delete the whole directory if it would be empty after the command.

Comment: Well, git doesn't want to delete the directory (otherwise it would have done so as in your second case, instead of complaining and continuing). Since `git-clean` by default ignores untracked directories (or rather, directories with no tracked files), it never enters them.

Comment: Ok, now I got the idea. The "... it never enters them" was the key ;)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

git does not keep track of directories - you can't commit an empty directory to git.

(try creating an empty directory, and adding it to git - you won't see any changes in git status)

Even if you add some files to an untracked directory, git won't show you all the files in `git status` - it will just show the directory

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590753/why-doesnt-git-version-directories) for more answers on why git doesn't version directories.

So as @Hasturkun pointed out in his answer, you need to pass  `-d` to `git clean` to remove untracked directories